# is there any limit on firestore rest api response size?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all the documents listed in firestore collection using FireStore Rest Api. I'm querying 3 collections and all of them have more than 200 records but api calls are not returning entire collection.

is there any limit or cap on how much data api can return? I see that there is pagination option but I'm trying to see if this can be achieved with single api call.

I'm using below url to make api calls
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${environment.firebase.projectId}/databases/(default)/documents/${collectionName}?pageSize=2000`

Below all 3 collections has more than 200 documents but they are consistently returning only 83,35,145 documents from the respective collection. Response size is from network tab and Stringfied Size is size after stringfy and saved to indexdb

**Summary**

[image]

**Indexdb: size after JSON.stringfy**
[image]

**Firestore Rest Api Calls summary**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried making API call using any API Client like Postman or Insomnia?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yeah initially I also thought browser might be having some restrictions, so tried with postman and there also its returning same no of records.